# Custom Matplotlib projection stereoplot: Schmidt projection

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, projection

So, I am trying to plot my data with the same code shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167550/custom-matplotlib-projection-schmidt-projection?noredirect=1&lq=1), including its latest update. But when I run the code to see the projection grid I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Python files\schmidt_projection.py", line 474, in <module>
    plt.subplot(111, projection="SchmidtProjection")

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1126, in subplot
    ax = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1402, in add_subplot
    ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 42, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Python files\schmidt_projection.py", line 26, in __init__
    Axes.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 511, in __init__
    self.cla()

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Python files\schmidt_projection.py", line 43, in cla
    self.set_longitude_grid(10)

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\Documents\Python files\schmidt_projection.py", line 309, in set_longitude_grid
    np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, number, True)[1:-1]))

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in linspace

  File "C:\Users\Stefano\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 113, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Does anybody know why and what can I do to fix this? I am relatively new in this, I am trying to learn as much as I can, but I can't figure out why this error occurs. I will really much appreciate any help. Thanks

p.s. I know that many years are passed since the post has been updated, but I still wanted to try if I could get help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through the code but my guess is that you're trying to use the `num` variable as an index. Indices (array or other) are typically integers. Your `num` might be interpreted as a float, so maybe you should cast it as an integer as `int(num)`, when using it as an index.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and it doesn't work. It keeps displaying this error